# Adobe Experience Manager Testing

Tags: testing

Basically am from QA department and have good experience in software testing. Recently committed in AEM technology project and am new to AEM. Can you please share the questionnaire / things i need to look before going for testing?

Answer (score 0):

As AEM based on components and services so you should first learn the basic terminology about AEM. For that you go through the [helpx](https://helpx.adobe.com/in/support/experience-manager.html) documents. 
Also here is the link to the [unit testing framework](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kt/eseminars/gems/aem-testing-tools-for-aem-apps.html)